# Recurring Work Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

I'd like to build a flow that kicks off once every 24 hrs. Its a 'Today' issue, which I know SP doesn't like very much.

I have a calculated column titled Compliance Status. The calculation is in part based on the system 'Modified' date column.

I need a process that will update the entire list every 24 hrs. Something simple like turn a 1 to a 2, then 24 hrs. later turn that 2 to a 1; an A to a B, it doesn't matter. Just a simple task that triggers a modification to the entire list, thus changing the content of the 'Modified' column for the entire list and forcing and update of the 'Compliance Status'.

Thoughts?

Comment: Add the logic for your "Compliance Status" column in a flow (I'm assuming you're using SharePoint Online) and schedule the flow to run once in 24 hours. If you need to use a flow, you don't require to use a "Calculated" column, the logic can be built within the flow.

Comment: Please clarify stages of the flow. I am familiar and have built a few; however, I've been known to spend untold hours wrongly building flows. I learn a lot, but waste a lot of time.

Shall it be a 'recurrence' flow? 

If not how should it be triggered? 

If a recurrence flow what is the next step (where I believe you are recommended the calculated column formula would go, yes?).

Comment: Yes, you can create a manual flow (in MS Flow/Power Automate) to develop/test etc. and then, when ready, convert its trigger from "Manual" to "Recurrence". Within the flow you can test column values to certain conditions for each items in the list and set the "Compliance Status" accordingly

Comment: Yes, I understand. My question was can you help with the action(s) I should set up in the flow? I'm not sure which one(s) to chose to accomplish the task. Am I Getting item, Getting items, Updating item, is there a delay, is there a condition or apply to all involved? I'm am unclear on the actual steps to chose to force the implementation of the transported calculated column formula.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a sceduled flow:

[image]

The flow action should be like this:

[image]